# How can I left-align text in bootstrap link button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to left-align the text in a bootstrap btn-link button but I can't get it to work. What is the right method? I have tried text-left class without success.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: `.btn, .btn-link {text-align:left}`? What’s wrong with this method?

Comment: Claire, I just tried that and it does not work.

Comment: I think your problem has to do with padding and not text alignment.

Comment: set text-align to the button parent’s tag

Comment: Majid, I am doing that with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Button has padding left and padding right. Try removing padding:

```
btn.btn-link {
  padding-left: 0
}
```